# Display Recipe Name based on ID MVC4

Tags: c#, html, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a list of recipes which store a foreign key of the Cuisine ID in the database.

I want my view model to display the "Name of the cuisine" based on this ID stored in the database. How do I do this ?

My Recipe Database looks like :

Name: Chicken Burger, Cuisine ID: 4
Name: Veg Example, Cuisine ID: 3

Cuisine Database is like:
Name: Indian Id = 1,
Name: Chinese, Id = 2, ... etc

I want my view model to display the Cuisine Name instead of the ID which is just for a database reference.

I am using Entity Framework to connect to my database, just need a good way in which I can display all the cuisine names for every recipe and the cuisine names will be pulled from the cuisine database depending on the ID which is stored in the recipe

Cuisine model

```
public class Cuisine
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CuisineName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TestRecipe> TestRecipes { get; set; }
}
```

Recipe Model

```
public class TestRecipe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CuisineId { get; set; }
    public virtual Cuisine Cuisine { get; set; }
}
```

Recipe Controller:

```
public class TestRecipeController : Controller
    {
        private FoodZillaDb db = new FoodZillaDb();
        //
        // GET: /TestRecipe/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var model = db.TestRecipes
                        .Take(10);

            return View(model);
        }

        //
        // GET: /TestRecipe/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // GET: /TestRecipe/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.CuisineId = new SelectList(db.Cuisines, "Id", "CuisineName");
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /TestRecipe/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(TestRecipe recipe)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.TestRecipes.Add(recipe);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.CuisineId = new SelectList(db.Cuisines, "Id", "CuisineName",recipe.CuisineId);
            return View("Index");
        }
```

I want the index view controller to send a cuisine name instead of the ID which is stored in the TestRecipe DB. I believe I have to do some kind of inner join?

Comment: Too broad. What have you done? What is your way to connect to DB? Entity framework? What did you try to do?

Comment: I am using Entity Framework to connect to my database, just need a good way in which I can display all the cuisine names for every recipe and the cuisine names will be pulled from the cuisine database depending on the ID which is stored in the recipe

Comment: Add code of controller and action method

Comment: I have added the code above. I want the Index controller to return a cuisine name along with all other values instead of only returning ForeignKey ID's. I believe I have to do some kind of inner join ? but I don't know exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query1 = from r in db.MyRecipe
             join c in db.Cuisine
            on c.Id equals r.Id

 select new MyViewModel()
  {
       CuisineName = c.Name
       Price = r.Name,
       ........
  };
```

Comment: brilliant. Thanks a lot, this was it !